# Averaging Time Stamps That Meet Certain Conditions in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, vba

Cell B is populated with a time stamp once data is entered into Cell A. Cell F is time stamped once Cell E data has been entered. Cell H is kept blank UNTIL both Cell B and Cell F have been timestamped. Cell H then calculates the difference between the timestamps.

My goal is to have another cell that displays the Sum of the AVERAGE Elapsed Time it has taken for all cells that are showing and elapsed time.

**For example:**

[image]

In the above image, you can see that the first 3 rows have been entered with data and an elapsed time is displayed. The 4th column does not have data entered, but the 5th column DOES have data entered (you might not be able to view it in the picture). I'd like a formula to calculate the overall average of the time elapsed in Column H, if there is a value greater than 00 seconds.

Comment: What is the formula to get the elapsed time?  Is the format a number format or is it a concatenated string?

Comment: Adding in a new issue. I want the Elapsed Time to show up and be used in the Average ONLY if the Status shows as "approved" or "denied". There is a third option (not currently showing in the image) that is "Pending Approval".

Answer (score 0):

If the data in column **H** is *formatted numeric data*, then in another cell enter the array formula:

```
=AVERAGE(IF(H1:H1000>0,H1:H1000))
```

**Array formulas** must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than just the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.  If this is done correctly, the formula will appear with curly braces around it in the Formula Bar.

Comment: Why not `AVERAGEIF(s)` instead of an array formula?

Comment: Actually AVERAGE() should skip the empty cells on its own.

Comment: @ScottCraner the poster specifically required the formula consider only values greater than zero, so I exclude both any zeros and blanks.

Comment: Ah, I see.  But won't `AVERAGEIF()` still do that without the need for CSE? `=AVERAGEIFS(H:H,H:H,">0")`  Or am I missing something else?

Comment: @ScottCraner  You are correct!  I forgot about `AVERAGEIFS()`

Comment: But this might all be a moot point if the cells are text and not a number formatted.

Comment: @ScottCraner,  -- thanks for your comments. The cells are formatted custom as ' dd"days" hh"hours" mm"minute" ss"seconds"

I tried the =AVERAGEIFS(H:H,H:H,">0") and at first try it seems to work. I'll comment further if I run into an issue. Thank you!